# Add Query Feature Class to ArcMap using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, sqlite, query-layer

Is there any way to add a feature class from a .sqlite database to ArcMap using ArcPy (Python)?

If I drag and drop the feature class from the .sqlite database, ArcMap creates a Query Feature Class, and it'll ask for a Unique Identifier Field. This all works perfectly, but so far I've been unable to find a way to do that through ArcPy / Python.

The Make Query Layer tool requires an SDE connection, but I can't figure out how to get that working with a .sqlite database.

I need it to be a Query Feature Class / Layer because the feature layer is not selectable in ArcMap.

Comment: Not tried it, as I don't really use .sqlite, but have a go at the Make Feature layer tool?

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't fix it as a regular feature layer with a .sqlite database is not selectable. :(

Comment: Given spatial data in SQLite databases can be created by multiple programs and can use different spatial data types, it might be useful to share what program created the SQLite database and what spatial data type is being used.

Comment: Will make query table do? It will use Shape field if included.

Comment: @bixb0012 I believe it uses Spatialite.

Comment: @FelixIP If I run Make Query Table on the feature class, it reports 'ERROR 000055: Cannot Create a Query Table for this workspace'.